# pass value to controller by using ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

I want to pass value from view to controller by using ajax.

```
 <button onclick="addCommentByAjax()" >Save</button>
```

> My script:

```
function addCommentByAjax() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/Survey/DoDetailSurvey',

        data: {
            choiceId: "1"
        }


});
}
```

> Controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult DoDetailSurvey(SurveyViewModel model, string choiceId)
    {
     //
    }
```

> but choiceId always null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function addCommentByAjax() {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/Survey/DoDetailSurvey?choiceId=1'
    }
});
}
```

You can also pass like this

or for more parameters

```
function addCommentByAjax() {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/Survey/DoDetailSurvey?choiceId=1&Name=Arun'
    }
});
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change couple of things.

First assign an id or class to your button.Second remove inline `onclick` function and use ajax `click` function.Then specify the request type as Post.

```
$('#btnComment').click(function () {       
    var choiceId = $('#YourChoiceId').val();

    $.ajax({
        url: '/Survey/DoDetailSurvey',
        data: { 'choiceId' : choiceId},
        type: "post",
        cache: false,
        success: function (response) {
           //do something with response
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
             alert('error occured');
        }
    });
});
```

Then your controller should look like this

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DoDetailSurvey(string choiceId)
{
     //
}
```

I don't know how you are populating your viewmodel,so I purposely removed them and shown an working example.

In case you want to pass viewmodel you should construct your data object like this:

```
var data = {};
data.Property1 = some val;
data.Property2 = "some val";   

$.post('/Survey/DoDetailSurvey', data);
```

Sample structure of SurveyViewModel  I assume:

```
public class SurveyViewModel 
{
    public int Property1 { get; set; }
    public string Property2 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I have tried like that but it still null, alert:error occured

Comment: use `JSON.Stringify`

Answer (score 1):

Since there are two parameter in your controller, you need to identify them both form the client side. Further, you should specify the `contentType`.

You spread the payload like so:

```
function addCommentByAjax() {
    var payload =  {
        model: {
        // whatever properties you might have
        },
        choiceId: 1
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/Survey/DoDetailSurvey',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify(payLoad)
    });
}
```